# Input, onChange CopyIt

Tags: javascript, input, onchange

I have this:

It is copying what I type in input1 to input2 and it strip spaces etc.

But it only copies when I'm hovering over input 2, is there a possibility to copy while typing?

input1

```
<input name="input1" type="text" id="input1" size="60" onchange = "copyItt()" />
```

input2

```
<input onclick="javascript:stripspaces(this)" onmouseover="javascript:stripspaces(this)" onkeydown="javascript:stripspaces(this)" name="input2" type="text" id="input2" readonly onmousemove="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();" onblur="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();"  size="60" />
```

javascript

```
function copyItt() {
var x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
document.getElementById("input2").value = x;
}

function stripspaces(input) 
{
input.value = input.value.replace(/\s/gi,"-");
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the `javascript:` prefix in the javascript event handlers such as `onclick`. That prefix is only needed when you use javascript in an `href` attribute (it acts as the protocol, letting the browser know to execute what follows as javascript instead of processing it as a URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll want to add `onkeyup="copyItt()"` to `intput1`, and you may also want to call `stripspaces()` from inside `copyItt()` so that the text is processed as you type:

```
function coypItt() {
    document.getElementById("input1").value;
    document.getElementById("input2").value = x;
    stripspaces(document.getElementById("input1"));
}
```

With this in place you may find that many (all?) of the event handlers on `input2` are unnecessary.